# Unity choose only one from all tagged gameObjects

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-engine, touchscreen

I have 100 cubes with name tag (card) and I want only the cube I press to be able to rotate.My code works but rotates all of the cubes with tag (card) Here is my code
I just need to rotate from the whole family of (card)tags only the object which I pressed

### everything else works fine

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneOneScript : MonoBehaviour
{


private bool canIRotate;
void Update()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {

                if (hit.collider.tag == "card")
                {
                    canIRotate = true;

                }
            }
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                canIRotate = false;
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {


                if (canIRotate == true)
                {
                       transform.LookAt(new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y,         transform.position.z));
                }


            }
        }






    }

}
}
```

Comment: Are the cubes child object of the GameObject that SceneOneScript is attached?

Comment: no they are not

Comment: It must be on the GameObject that has the Camera on then?

Answer (score 1):

Using RayCast is good solution:

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)    
{
     Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
     RaycastHit hit;
     Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, Color.yellow, 100f);
     if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
     {
         Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
         if (hit.collider != null) {

             GameObject touchedObject = hit.transform.gameObject;

             Debug.Log("Touched " + touchedObject.transform.name);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this is not working form me too

Comment: i suppose you have collider on each cube? have you a hit when you debug?

Comment: I I hitting but it is not working like I want to work maybe I should explane better

Comment: There is a grid of cubes 10 by 10 cubes so I want to click a cube the cube goes forward then while clickHolding rotate the cube and when I release the cube should stay rotated like this and when I click the rotated cube again it shuld return to its normal rotation back in the grid and all cubes have to be able to be clicked and rotated separately one from another

Comment: the problem is that when I select the cube with tag name card all cubes rotate and I want to rotate only one cube from the grid with 100 cubes with tag card

Comment: yes but how do I implement it in my piece of code I don't know :/

Comment: what i say you have another issue..you ask to choose one cube from 100... if you have another issue, i suggest you to open another question and take the time to explain all things. its just to avoid to pollute the initial question...Your new issue is how to rotate and not select

Comment: I am saying that my code rotates and works good but it is selecting all of the cubes I want to change my code to select only one cube and do what it does now

Comment: when you ask your new question, imagine you have to answer....   .. you'll see the diffculty..; so detailled question means a good solution. and avoid to loose time

Comment: I know its hard to explain things to starters like me but I am trying my best also new in the unity community so don't judge just looking for answers to my problem here

Comment: no problem anko i am pretty cool..and i see your effort..but your other problem needs more details. believe me..

Comment: Good answer from Frenchy, its what you are looking for just glue it into your code :)